# Merging YAML Keys

Tags: yaml, gitlab-ci

Im trying to create a very abstract `.yaml`-configuration which can be reused in different places.

Right now it looks like this:

```
.release: &release
  stage: release
  script:
    - docker tag $IMAGE_TESTING $IMAGE_RELEASE
    - docker push $IMAGE_RELEASE
  only: 
    - master
  when: manual

.amd64: &amd64
    BASE_ARCH: 'amd64'

.debalike: &debalike
    FLAVOUR: 'debalike'

release_debalike_amd64:
  <<: *release
  variables:
    << : [*amd64, *debalike]
```

Which correctly gets parsed into ...

```
.release:
    stage: release
    script:
        - 'docker tag $IMAGE_TESTING $IMAGE_RELEASE'
        - 'docker push $IMAGE_RELEASE'
    only:
        - master
    when: manual
.amd64:
    BASE_ARCH: amd64
.debalike:
    FLAVOUR: debalike
release_debalike_amd64:
    stage: release
    script:
        - 'docker tag $IMAGE_TESTING $IMAGE_RELEASE'
        - 'docker push $IMAGE_RELEASE'
    only:
        - master
    when: manual
    variables:
        BASE_ARCH: amd64
        FLAVOUR: debalike
```

Which is the desired behaviour.

But would it be possible to avoid using the variables tag in `release_debalike_amd64` and use include the anchors directly?

Something similar to this (which does not work):

```
.release: &release
  stage: release
  script:
    - docker tag $IMAGE_TESTING $IMAGE_RELEASE
    - docker push $IMAGE_RELEASE
  only: 
    - master
  when: manual

.amd64: &amd64
    variables:
        BASE_ARCH: 'amd64'

.debalike: &debalike
    variables:
        FLAVOUR: 'debalike'

release_debalike_amd64:
  <<: *release
  <<: [*amd64, *debalike]
```

Right now the yaml parser ignores the `*debalike` and just includes the values from `*amd64`.

Any way to achieve this? **This is a .gitlab-ci.yml if it matters.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not. It is not possible to do deep merges using only YAML anchors and aliases.

GitLab EE introduced CI includes in 10.5, which was enhanced in 10.8 to do deep merges of CI jobs. I don't think it's going to help you in this particular case, but it's something you might be able to leverage in other ways depending on how you organize your CI files.

See [include](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#include) for more information about the include parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! As im a CE user, includes are not an option. Looks like I have to live with the current version.